# Formatted message on a DB can be retrieved locally but not on the live site

Tags: c#, asp.net, label, repeater

I'm sorry if the title may seem vague, but I dont /actually/ know how to put it.
Anyone who can change it for the better is welcome.

I am using a `Repeater` control to read messages from a Database, and display them on a `Label`.

Through VS2010, I am able to happily see and display the message. But, when I publish the site, it appears with this warning:

```
Attempt by method 'System.Web.UI.DataBinder.GetIndexedPropertyValue(System.Object, System.String)' to access method 'System.Data.Common.DataRecordInternal.get_Item(System.String)' failed.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.MethodAccessException: Attempt by method 'System.Web.UI.DataBinder.GetIndexedPropertyValue(System.Object, System.String)' to access method 'System.Data.Common.DataRecordInternal.get_Item(System.String)' failed.

Source Error: 


Line 106:                <asp:Panel ID="pnlModuleHolder" class="module blue" runat="server">
Line 107:                    <h2>
Line 108:                        <asp:Label ID="lblTitle" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("[newsColumnTitle]")%>' Font-Bold="True"></asp:Label>
Line 109:                        <a href='<%# "NewsReport?report=" +Eval("[id]") %>'>Read More</a></h2>
Line 110:                </asp:Panel>

Source File: f:\Domains\SEE47\ocdbt.whatyouneed.com\wwwroot\Default.aspx    Line: 108
```

I have never seen this before, and because it is working on my local site, I cant really step through and debug for an answer.

Has anyone had any experience on this before?

Here is a snippet of the message, which is stored in the DB.

```
<p style="font-family: Arial; line-height: 18px;"><strong>Welcome to the Beta build and release of the O
```

Comment: Ensured that "newsColumnTitle" and "id" exists in both your development and publishing environnements ? Also, does it work when no html markup ?

Comment: They are both reading off the same live DB. I've change the entire message to simply `Test`, and it still has that error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[According to this blog](http://arahuman.blogspot.com/2008/09/systemmethodaccessexception.html):

> In a Medium trust environment, according to Microsoft "Reflection is not allowed". Looks like when you assign a datareader to a repeater control internally it is doing some reflection which is causing this issue. Another strange behaviour with this error is it won't even tell you the exact error ...

He says to reproduce locally change the following in `web.config`:

```
<system.web>
    <trust level="Medium" />
</system.web>
```

And his final workaround was to use `DataSet` instead of `DataReader`.

Comment: Sorry for the long wait. This does recreate the error... I fixed it by using a Generic list, then binding that list to the repeater.